# Use embedded JDK

Tags: android

I have just installed the latest version of Android Studio.
I installed it before JDK on the mac.
So it seems I did things in the wrong order.

When I look at my project strucutre, I see that 'use embedded JDK' is recommended. Does it work well in this case?
Should I reinstall Android Studio now JDK is installed?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Simply change that path to JDK installation path.

Comment: Thanks Shashanth, I didn't see where was installed the JDK on mac and I found it with this path : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I reinstall Android Studio now JDK is installed?

Why would you do this?

In the same location that recommends the embedded JDK, you can simply change that to the installed one.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the path.